# Android Kotlin - check if image from Gallery is animated GIF

Tags: android, kotlin

This is what I've tried:

```
try {

    val file = File(selectedPhotoUri!!.path)
    //val file = File(selectedPhotoUri.toString()) // this isn't working too
    val fileInputStream = FileInputStream(file)
    val outStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    var len = 0
    while (fileInputStream.read(buffer).also { len = it } != -1) {
        outStream.write(buffer, 0, len)
    }
    fileInputStream.close()
    val bytes = outStream.toByteArray()
    val gif = Movie.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size)
    //If the result is true, its a animated GIF
    if (gif != null) {
        Log.d(tagg, "is gif")
    } else {
        Log.d(tagg, "is not gif")
    }
} catch (ie: IOException) {
    ie.printStackTrace()
}
```

I don't get any result, `Movie.decodeByteArray` is deprecated and it looks like I need to use `AnimatedImageDrawable` instead, but how?

Comment: you can check by the URL  suffix

Comment: I'll do that in case there isn't a solution to check if it's a true GIF :D Because users can just rename the file extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ImageDecoder` class, it will recognize types of provided image sources to decode, for static images it will create `BitmapDrawable` and for animated images — `AnimatedImageDrawable`.

```
val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(assets, assetFileName)
val drawable = ImageDecoder.decodeDrawable(source)

imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable)

if (drawable is AnimatedImageDrawable) {

  // it is a GIF, and you can play the animation by calling drawable.start()

} else {

  // it is not a GIF

}
```

Comment: You can implement another set of condition if API < 27 using `Movie.decodeByteArray`, which was deprecated in API 28